# Elastic Search HightlevelRestClient SearchRequest Timeout issue

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am forming a SearchRequest and by using ElasticSearch `RestHighLevelClient` am trying to fetch documents from ElasticSearch. But, while search documents in ES am getting the below error.

Please find the stack trace below :

```
`18-Sep-2018 06:35:55.819 SEVERE [Thread-10] com.demo.searchengine.dao.DocumentSearch.getDocumentByName listener timeout after waiting for [30000] ms
 java.io.IOException: listener timeout after waiting for [30000] ms
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:663)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:222)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:194)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:443)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:429)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:368)
    at com.demo.searchengine.dao.DocumentSearch.getDocumentByName(DocumentSearch.java:76)
    at com.demo.searchengineservice.mqservice.Service.searchByDocuments(Service.java:43)
    at com.demo.searchengineservice.mqservice.Consumer.consume(Consumer.java:27)
    at com.demo.utils.Consumer$1$1.run(Consumer.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

Please find my code below :

```
public class SearchEngineClient {
    private static PropertiesFile propertiesFile = PropertiesFile.getInstance();

    private final static String elasticHost =propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("ELASTIC_HOST");

    private static RestHighLevelClient instance = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost(elasticHost, 9200, "http"),
            new HttpHost(elasticHost, 9201, "http")));

    public static RestHighLevelClient getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Am using the client instance below to getting the response from ES.

```
searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance().search(contentSearchRequest);
```

Comment: Can you access the elastic server from the application server? try telnet on the ip/port of the provided elastic server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your elasticsearch server being not reachable from the outside. The ES server will only bind to localhost by default, which means it is not reachable from the outside.

So on your remote ES server you should find the elasticsearch.yml configuration file. In this file find and change network.host to your IP address or 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces. After that change you need to restart ES.